# How to get the selected rows(and their values) from a Tabular Form with javascript in Oracle Apex 5

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I am trying to get values in a selected row from a Tabular Form and want to put these in an array so I can send them with an apex aplication process. I don't know how to get the selected records and their values from a Tabular Form. At the end I want this data to be copied(duplicated) but one of the selected values (the weeknumber) should be changed.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: To make it more understandable. I have a Tabular Form. I want to duplicate the rows I have selected in the Tabular Form but with 1 column modified. So for example:

```
Row 1 = A-B-C
Row 2 = A-D-E
```

If these two rows are selected I want these two rows to be copied but then with the first column modified like this:

```
Row 1 = A-B-C
Row 2 = A-D-E
Row 3 = Z-B-C
Row 4 = Z-D-E
```

As you can see the first rows have been copied to row 3 and 4 but the first column has been changed from A to Z.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "At the end I want this data to be copied(duplicated)"? Copied where?

Comment: I want the values of all the rows that the user has selected(checked with a checkbox) to be copied. I have found a kind of solution to knowing when a row is selected. each column and row have an id like "f01_0001" where the last 4 digits reperesent the rownumber. The question now is how to fetch all rows so i can loop through all the rows and check if the value of "f01_0001" = "1". For the second row it would be like "f01_0002" = "1"

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. Are you saying you'd like to add a new row based on an existing row (except the one column)? If so, that kind of thing is tricky. Not impossible, but there are edge cases to consider. Have you considered upgrading APEX to leverage Interactive Grids instead?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do. But it must also be possible to copy(add) multiple rows based on the selected row. Let me give an example: 
Row 1 = A-B-C || Row 2 = A-E-F.

I want to copy these 2 rows and should be changed like:
Row 3 = A-B-C => Z-B-C || Row 4 = A-E-F => Z-E-F.

As you can see these 2 rows are from row 1 and 2 but column 1 is changed from A to Z. Upgrading APEX is outside my hands. It's for work and we work on a server that is running Oracle APEX 5.2.

Comment: @DanMcGhan I edited the quastion for an explanation of what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: Please check your version of APEX again - there is no 5.2. Doing this kind of thing on a tabular form is hacky and dependent on a number of things, such as the source of your region. If you create an example on apex.oracle.com that closely replicates your situation and provide me with developer credentials, I'll take a look. However, you'd probably be better off saying you can't do what's requested until you upgrade and can leverage the proper APIs of the Interactive Grid region.